# Fixing conditional state behavior for rendering for Mui <Cards>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a list of Mui cards. On a card hover, I would like a Floating Action Button to appear inside the card. I'm using state to achieve this, the issue is that the hover state is being applied to ALL cards during state change, meaning the button is showing up on every card, and not the one that's being pointed at/hovered. How can I control this to that the button is only showing on THE card where the state action was being fired off.

Also, is there anyway to not cause state change to re-render other components? I have a `<ChartistGraph>` that is being re-rendered on hover which constantly has it's animation repeated.

Essentially this is what I'm doing:

```
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        actionButton: false
    });
```

My card:

```
                        <Card
                          className="miniGraphCards"
                          onMouseOver={() => setState({ actionButton: true })}
                          onMouseOut={() => setState({ actionButton: false })}
                        >
```

Conditional rendering based off state and hover:

```
                            {state && state.actionButton != false &&
                              <Fab>
                                <EmojiEmotionsIcon />
                              </Fab>}
```

Please see reproducible code: You will notice the repeat re-rendering of the graphs and the button being applied to all cards on hover.

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-kowalevski-j3wjx

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the 'state' on the `App` component. Your boolean `actionButton` will trigger for all the items.

Since you want the `App` to know what item is active/hover, consider saving a **unique** value of that `Card`, so you can determine wich `Card` is being hovered on.

Since I still know how the app works from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66480636/how-to-map-an-array-of-children-items-for-a-carousel), I would recommend to save the `data.symbol` for the `Card` you are hovering on.

First, onHover, remember the *current* `data.symbol`

```
<Card
    onMouseOver={() => setState({ actionButton: data.symbol })}
    onMouseOut={() => setState({ actionButton: null })}
>
```

The, while looping over all the Cards, you can check if the curent one needs an icon like so:

```
{state && state.actionButton === data.symbol && (
    <Fab>
        <EmojiEmotionsIcon />
    </Fab>
)}
```

[Updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-microservice-gsyxw)

Comment: Thank you for the help, is there anyway I can stop my graph component from re-rendering due to the state change via hover?

Comment: Yea, you should add a component between the `App` and each `Card` so that each `Card` can keep it's own state. This will prevent any re-rendering.

Comment: What do you refer to when you say "add a component between `App` and each `Card`?

Comment: Kinda hard to explain using just comment ;) Make start reading questions like this one: [How to prevent react from re-rendering the whole component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763031/how-to-prevent-react-from-re-rendering-the-whole-component) or [this](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/)